# Trying to set up Android SDK - Please help! Beginner

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, android-emulator

So I am super new to this, and am not really sure what I am doing.

I downloaded the Android SDK for Windows, but I am a little confused in setting it up/installing. So I read that I needed to set the System Variables Path to the tools/

but I it seems that I would be replacing the Windows\System32?!?!

I should not be replacing this should I?

Windows Vista; already have the Eclipse IDE download and set up (minus pointing at the SDK)

Can anyone help a begginer out with setting this thing up please?

apreciated; thanks!

also: i should metion exactly what I have done...

I downloaded that Android SDK and unzipped it.....that's about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the Linux version of the SDK but I can probably still help you. I followed [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) exactly and everything worked out for me.

The next thing to do after unzipping and adding tools/ to the PATH, is to run 'android' this is a GUI program in the tools/ directory and it will allow you to create at least one Virtual Android platform for the emulator to run. just use all the defaults and the latest android version when setting that up. again all these instructions are available in more detail at the link above.

after you got that part done, you need to install eclipse if you haven't already. almost all Android development is done in eclipse with a plugin called [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). although it is possible not to use eclipse and ADT, the tutorials and everything expect you to be using it.

after you install that try the [hello world program](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Comment: the link above is actually what I was going off of.

So I unzipped the files, and added tools/ to the PATH, but now what.
I tried to run the SDK Setup.exe and keep getting this error message instantly "fetch error"?? 

How do I run 'android'?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Still an error there..."Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing your swt.jar.."

Comment: go into the tools folder and double click android.bat I think.

Comment: if that just opens it in a text editor, right click it and see if you can find a way of running it. sorry I am unfamiliar with windows.

Comment: remember, after that you just leave it alone. go install eclipse and ADT.

Comment: thanks for the help! i am sure I will figure this stuff out. Got it going, Eclipse and ADT done, and now downloading SDK tool packages. appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

The PATH environment variable is a semi-colon (;) list of paths. Just append a ";" + the Android SDK tools path to the end.

Answer (score 1):

add to path, put a ; then add to the end....

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post about what steps to take on a Windows machine to get started with Android development using Eclipse as your development environment (Windows 7, 64-bit in my case, but I don't think there is anything 7/64 specific in the list). I guess the points could have even more detail (no screenshots), but I basically typed them down so that I would remember them myself.

[Getting ready for Android development](http://www.mikeplate.com/getting-ready-for-android-development/)

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html) is an must read for starting android development, lot of good information on how to configure eclipse, installing adt etc.

And next up, get yourself an [subscription](http://commonsware.com/) here:

And the [official android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) is one of the best I've seen for development platforms.